# Open dialog box (Open File...) in Emacs with keyboard shortcut

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, I make no use of the default command linked with +. Hence, I would like to use this keyboard shortcut to open the graphical dialog box for "Open File...". How should I proceed to set this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in your `.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "+") (lambda ()
                            (interactive)
                            (let (last-nonmenu-event)
                              (menu-find-file-existing))))
```

Then either type <kbd>M-x eval-buffer</kbd> or restart Emacs.

**However** - are you really absolutely sure that you will never ever need the <kbd>+</kbd> for anything else (such as, say, inserting a `+`)? Perhaps consider using at least something like <kbd>CTRL +</kbd> as your keyboard shortcut instead of just <kbd>+</kbd>... this could easily be implemented by replacing `"+"` in the above code snippet with `"C-+"`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Thomas's answer (and I'd pose the same question about using `+`):

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "+") (lambda ()
                            (interactive)
                            (let (use-file-dialog)
                              (menu-find-file-existing))))
```

Dunno which is better, or whether it matters. But at least this way you will perhaps have done `C-h v use-file-dialog` to understand what that variable does and hence why this code does what you want.

(`menu-find-file-existing` is just the command that menu-bar `File` > `Open File...` is bound to. It's what `C-h k` tells you when you click that menu item.)

Comment: Thank you for this similar answer! The one above worked slightly better to my expectations :)